# How to write a jsonArray to kafka topic in node js

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, apache-kafka

How to write an array(has json strings) to Kakfa topic in node js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
server.on('package:publish', async event => {
  try {
    const responses = await producer.send({
      topic: process.env.TOPIC,
      messages: [{
        // Name of the published package as key, to make sure that we process events in order
        key: event.name,

        // The message value is just bytes to Kafka, so we need to serialize our JavaScript
        // object to a JSON string. Other serialization methods like Avro are available.
        value: JSON.stringify(array)
      }]
    })

    console.log('Published message', { responses })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error publishing message', error)
  }
})
```

The message value is just bytes to Kafka, so we need to serialize our JavaScript
object to a JSON string. Other serialization methods like Avro are available.

Just wrap your array data as `JSON.stringify(array)` and send it in value,
and at consumer end you can parse it using `JSON.parse(message.value)`

Here are some links for help https://www.confluent.io/blog/getting-started-with-kafkajs/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node#producer